# Find Vowels using Regex

Tags: java, regex

Looking for Maximum length of string which have maximum length with all vowels,

For Example :-

```
    aeiaaioooaauuaeiou
response :- 
    aeiou
    aeeiou
    aaaaeiou
    aaeiou
    aaeiou
    aeiiou
    ...
    aeiiooouuu
    ...
    aeiiooouuu
```

But result will be (aeiiooouuu) 10,

I'm unable to get single and repeted charater

```
My code :- 

    String str ="aeiaaioooaauuaeiou";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([aAeEiIoOuU])\\1{0,}");

    Matcher m =p.matcher(str) ;
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to match substrings that are missing in your input string. This is not possible with just a regex. Please explain the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A more accurate pattern could be `[aAeEiIoOuU]+`. You might want to look at [quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) in regular expressions. This pattern is greedy so it will return the largest possible match.

Comment: Thanks for response, I need to separate print as a my example

Comment: what do you mean by separate print?

Comment: aeiaaioooaauuaeiou
response :- 
    aeiou
    aeeiou
    aaaaeiou
    aaeiou
    aaeiou
    aeiiou
    ...
    aeiiooouuu
    ...
    aeiiooouuu